# How do I see invited users in bintray?

Tags: bintray

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Sign up for a new enterprise trial.
2. Go to the Organization Edit screen.
3. Click on the **Members** section.
4. Click on **invite by email**.
5. User clicks on received email.
6. They create an account using the pattern of *username@orgid*.
7. The admin cannot see them in an member lists.
8. The user cannot see any products or repos.

I can admin a user just fine if they create a full bintray account, but we would like to not tell our users that they need to create a new account, which right now also forces them to create a new organization also.

What step am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

This was a temporary issue with invite-by-email members not being shown in the members list (judging by the time the question was raised). It should all be okay now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I can only see invite by username button on members list? Where is the invite by email located?